# I'm getting Member 'Version' was not found error sometimes, but not all times when using BinaryFormatter.Deserialize() with dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, serialization, binaryformatter

I have a Unity game on Steam that serializes game save state using BinaryFormatter, and stores and retrieves the data using Steam Cloud Saving. Rarely, the save files for users is failing to load and throws the following error:

```
Member 'Version' was not found.  at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetElement (System.String name, System.Type& foundType) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetInt32 (System.String name) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].OnDeserialization (System.Object sender) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize (System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler handler, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser serParser, System.Boolean fCheck) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

If the users quit the game and restart a variable number of times, this problem will stop occuring and they will be able to load normally.

What I would love is a better understanding of what might cause this error so I can potentially track down what is happening in my case.

Some additional information:

- Deserializing an empty file fails with warnings and no errors, so I believe they are loading the file.
- Deserializing a file with gibberish fails with warning and no errors.

I did discover a place in my saving code where I was breaking some rules that smells like it could be related, but I'm largely trying to find more information here to know for sure. I broke [this rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/code-quality/ca2218-override-gethashcode-on-overriding-equals?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN) in a custom vector3 object I was serializing. My Equals() override could potentially return false for two objects with the same hash code as I was directly comparing float values in Equals() while converting to Unity's Vector3 and using its GetHashCode (see code below).

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return new Vector3(x, y, z).GetHashCode();
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj is SimpleVector3 sv3)
    {
        return sv3.x == x && sv3.y == y && sv3.z == z;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Would it make sense that this particular error message could result from a floating point error causing non-consistent behavior between serializing and de-serializing?

Mainly what I'm needing help with are clues of where to look based on this error message. I am not entirely sure what it might mean.

Thanks!

Comment: In general [**STOP using `BinaryFormatter` at all!**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) .. rather go for the [alternatives](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) `Json`, `Xml` or write your custom instance <-> byte[] serialization

Comment: And about the `Equals` .. why not rather use a proper comparison than? either again via the Hashcode or using `Mathf.Approxiamtely` or use a certain range (e.g. `Vector3 ==` only has a precision of `1e-5`)

Comment: The "rule"/warning you are referring to though doesn't mean it has to return `true` if the hashes match .. it rather is thrown if you override `Equals` but do **not** override `GetHashCode`

Comment: In general the `BinaryFormatter` (besides stop moving it!) is quite error prone when you try to extend / change the type and in particular fields and properties that are to be (de)serialized ... it sounds like you either added or removed/renamed a field/property called `Version` so now the `BinaryFormatter` doesn't work with that type/files anymore ... as said you should rather go for e.g. JSON wher this is not an issue at all. And then publish a version that offers a migration for previous `BinaryFormatter` files into JSON and get rid of it as soon as possible ;)

Comment: Great advice, thank you! It does sound like I need to migrate away from BinaryFormatter. In any case, I am curious what would cause this error to appear intermittently on the same build version.